# Are there any significant properties of that quotient space of $[0,1]$ by the Cantor set?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, cantor-set

The Cantor set has two interesting properties of being nowhere dense and uncountably infinite. I was curious what sort of quotient space is made when you take $[0,1]$ by the Cantor set. In other words, gluing all Cantor points to a single point.

Comment: Do you mean the Cantor set in $[0,1]$? So the space will be identical to $\mathbb R$ anywhere else?

Comment: @DonThousand My bad. It is late. I meant $[0,1]$, not $\mathbb{R}$. I will edit the question.

Comment: What do you mean map of my choice? There is only one map: the quotient map that maps $[0,1]$ to the quotient set where all cantor points are in one equivalence class, and all other points are contained in their own singleton classes.

Comment: I suspect you get something not unlike the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring).

Comment: In general, quotients are not well known / classified generally.

Comment: @DonThousand Why is that?

Comment: Because they are hard to deal with? I don't really think there's a good answer to that.

Comment: Do you mean "gluing all points on Cantor set into one single point"?

Comment: @edm Yea I was confused by that as well. OP worded it weirdly, but that is what OP seems to want.

Comment: @edm Yes, all cantor points glued to a single point.

Comment: Isn't that the standard notion of quotienting a topological space by a subset? Is there another interpretation?

Comment: I think the result would be the one-point compactification of the complement of the Cantor set in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $[0,1]$ is compact and the Cantor set is closed, the quotient space will also be compact.

Note: I'll denote the single point of the image of the Cantor set under the canonical map as the Cantor point. I'll also denote the quotient space as $X$.

Now consider the open cover of the quotient space that consists of an arbitrary open neighbourhood of the Cantor point, and the individual images of all the open intervals taken away from $[0,1]$ to obtain the Cantor set. This clearly is an open cover of $X$, and since $X$ is compact, it must have a finite subcover.

Now obviously the intervals don't cover the Cantor point, therefore any subcover must contain the open neighbourhood of the Cantor point. But then, the finite subcover only contains a finite subset of the open intervals, therefore the open neighbourhood of the Cantor point covers all but finitely many intervals.

Note that for any point on one of the intervals, there exists a neighbourhood consisting only of points of that interval, and the subspace topology of a single interval together with the Cantor point is easily seen to be that of a circle.

Therefore the quotient space is like the Hawaiian earring, but with uncountably many circles.

Note that since the complement of the Cantor point is open, this set is the one-point compactification of $[0,1]\setminus C$.

Comment: Wow it’s homeomorphic to the Hawaiian earring even though it has uncountably many circles?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler: Oops, you're right, I didn't think of the cardinality. I'll fix.